# Sending diffrent data to all sockets with socket.io on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
io.sockets.emit('data', data);
```

Hello, this emits to all the sockets, but each socket gets the same data, is it possible for me to emit to them all, but give each of them different data?

Comment: you could loop through all your connected clients and emit different data to them. You can find the list of clients by doing `io.sockets.clients();`

Comment: Thank you didn't thought of that, such an obvious answer now. You should post your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. It will depend on what you want to do really (and how). First thing that came to my mind as a alternative is identifying your users by `socket.id` and then send them the data accordingly.

Example:

```
io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) {
    if(socket.id == 1337) data = {test: "test1"};
    if(socket.id == 404) data = {test: "test2"};

    socket.emit('data',data);
});
```

Comment: I want to send kinda random data, so the io.sockets.clients() forEach serves its purpose just right, but if I wanted to send targeted data this would probably serve its purpose. Seeing that Houseman didn't post his own answer I'm gonna accept this one.